# Cloud Vision billing/pricing inconsistency

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-vision

I was just glossing over my billing history and to my surprise found out I've been charged $28.71 for *Cloud Vision API Cloud Vision API Label Detection Operations*. I'm really confused because it says I have "5356 counts".

[The Cloud Vision pricing table](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pricing) lists 1001-1000000 units as $5.00 for Label Detection.

Is this a mistake on Google's billing or am I interpretting the pricing incorrectly? I've read over the description several times and am not sure how I could be misunderstanding the breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

> Price per 1000 units

If the count includes free quota then you have 4356 units. If the units are rounded up to 5000, then you have 5 units x $5 = 25 (+ tax?)

[Pricing Chart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pricing)

Answer (score 0):

npe's answer is accurate. Adding more details that I have.
Had the same issue. I mailed the sales team and the 
https://cloud.google.com/vision/

The tag they added to resolve any such confusions is : "Price per 1,000 units, by monthly usage"

Thanks
Suman